# Two-way interprocess communication (via Named pipes) - WCF or .Net Remoting?

Tags: wcf, remoting, ipc

I have what seems to be a fairly common inter-process communication requirement - a parent process spawns some child processes, and the parent process and child processes need to be able to perform two-way communication with each other (the child process needs to keep the parent process up-to-date with its state and the parent process needs to be able to check that the child process is still alive - note that the child processes don't need to communicate with each other).

I've been looking into doing this using WCF, but I'm new to using WCF for this sort of IPC - as far as I can tell in order to get this two-way communication I'd need both the parent process and the child process to expose WCF services, which seems like a bit of a faff.

On the other hand .Net Remoting makes this sort of communication almost seamless, but everyone seems to be of the opinion that Remoting is old-hat and I should use WCF instead.

So I'm struggling to choose the approach I should take:
 - My goal is to make the communication as uncomplicated as possible.
 - Security isn't really an issue.

Which should I choose?

Comment: I would and still use remoting instead of WCF (especially for IPC).

Comment: You should correct the question title , WCF instead of WPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both technologies should be suitable for what you want to do. The main design difference between the two APIs is:

- Remoting is designed to make all interfaces look local, regardless of their origin.
- WCF is designed to make all interfaces look remote, regardless of their origin.

WCF appears to be more complex because it exposes the complexity rather than hiding it. Since your stated goal is to remove code complexity, you might as well go for Remoting.

Having said that, WCF will allow you to evolve your implementation later on, e.g. change protocols, add security, etc. Only if you are absolutely sure you will never need to do this should you drop WCF.

I prefer the WCF approach for everything, but that's a very subjective preference.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how talkative your applications (parent and children) are.

If communication is rather basic you can go for .NET Remoting, but if you have a more complex communication scheme, I (personally) would go with WCF.